# Silverlight method complete run more times

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight

I have a problem with my silverlight app. I am using WCF and Bing maps. I am showing some data on map and these data are taken from database by WCF. The problem is the complete method run more times. 
i call asynch method

```
private void vsetciBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (krajCBB.SelectedIndex < 0)
     client.VratVsetkychPacientovCompleted += client_VratVsetkychPacientovCompleted;
        client.VratVsetkychPacientovAsync(krajCBB.SelectedIndex < 0 ? -2 : kraje[krajCBB.SelectedIndex].Id,
            okresCBB.SelectedIndex < 0 ? -1 : okresy[okresCBB.SelectedIndex].Id, "Vsetci pacienti");
}
```

and the answer

```
void client_VratVsetkychPacientovCompleted(object sender, ServiceMaps.VratVsetkychPacientovCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  surad = e.Result;
  zobrazsuradnice(surad)
}
```

so when i click on button its is working and method zobrazsuradnice(surad); show the data but if i do it again then client_VratVsetkychPacientovCompleted run 2 times, if again it run 3 times
Any idea why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
client.VratVsetkychPacientovCompleted += client_VratVsetkychPacientovCompleted;    
private void vsetciBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (krajCBB.SelectedIndex != 0 && krajCBB.SelectedIndex > 0)
    client.VratVsetkychPacientovAsync(krajCBB.SelectedIndex < 0 ? -2 : kraje[krajCBB.SelectedIndex].Id,
        okresCBB.SelectedIndex < 0 ? -1 : okresy[okresCBB.SelectedIndex].Id, "Vsetci pacienti");
}
```

//Completed event

```
void client_VratVsetkychPacientovCompleted(object sender, ServiceMaps.VratVsetkychPacientovCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    surad = e.Result;
    zobrazsuradnice(surad);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt help. this condition is not imporant

Comment: @user3426333 it's not about condition. Create completed event outside the button click and check

Comment: ohh yeah i didnt see it before
thanks its is working